# How can I change the quality of my thumbnails?

Tags: image, thumbnail

My product image looks very good but somehow magento is making my thumbnails looking pretty bad. How can I fix this problem?(Setting?/Code?) Thank you!

Comment: pls try code : 

$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200)->setQuality(100);

Answer (score 1):

There are few function exit in magento.

use `setQuality()`  for improve the quality of image.

Also Need  to use `resize()` of $this->helper('catalog/image') properly at your code.

See more details at http://astrio.net/blog/images-resize-in-magento/

Comment: Any thoughts why magento is causing such troubles with my thumbnails?

Comment: Please sh how your code